# JasperReport экспорт в excel

Tags: excel, report

Пользуюсь jasperReport для создания отчетов. Возникла необходимость экспортировать отчеты в excel.
Прописал свойства отчету:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics" value="false"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="false"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.page.break.no.pagination" value="apply"/>
```

Получается неплохо, но есть но:

В столбце "Наименование", строка 21, не происходит автоподбор высоты ячейки как в строке 22 (столбец "Наименование")
и то же самое в столбце "Операция" не происходит автоподбор высоты ячейки
Пробовал свойства:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
```

Не помогает. ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ???
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В связи в особенностями MS Excel автоматический подбор высоты не работает в объединённых ячейках таблицы. Чтобы автоподбор работал корректно, нужно изменить шаблон JR таким образом, чтобы в результате экспорта ячейки, которые могут содержать несколько строк, не были объединёнными.